# Why do US passport cards have such limited usage?

Tags: usa, passports, identity-cards

[US passport cards](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/card.html) have limited usage:

> Entering the United States at land border crossings and sea ports-of-entry from:
>
> - Canada
> - Mexico
> - The Caribbean
> - Bermuda
>
> The passport card cannot be used for international air travel.

Why the limitations on usage and is it likely to change?

Comment: Probably because it was a part of: [WHTI](http://consumertraveler.com/columns/passport-or-passport-card-%E2%80%94-which-is-best-for-foreign-travel/)

Comment: The passport card doesn't conform to ICAO specifications for passports.

Comment: @MichaelHampton neither do EU national ID cards, yet those can be used for international air travel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The passport card is a card -- it doesn't have any pages to it, thus there is no place for visas or entry/exit stamps.

Thus, it can only be used to travel to places where no visa is needed and where there are treaties in place to ensure that enough data is exchanged between immigration departments so that they can keep track of you without stamps.

As the use of the cards usually involve bilateral and reciprocal treaties -- and few countries have passport cards to reciprocate -- it's unlikely that more countries will accept American passport cards in the near future.

Comment: "and few countries have passport cards to reciprocate" - most of the EU does.

Comment: -1: This doesn't address the question of why passport cards can be used to travel to certain countries by land or sea, but not by air.  In fact, the restriction is imposed by US law, not by other countries.

Comment: @JonathanReez It looks like EU passport cards are only valid for Schengen-area and EU travel, and you need to have a standard passport to qualify for one.  Americans can get a passport card even if they lack a traditional passport.  It's sort of like a mini-passport, with a lower cost, and more restricted usability.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie nope. EU ID cards are the primary form of identification for most EU citizens (the UK being a notable exception as they don't issue ID cards).  You need an ID card to qualify for a passport, not the other way around. And they are accepted beyond the EU (e.g. in Turkey and Georgia). For a full list see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identity_cards_in_the_European_Economic_Area#Use

Comment: @JonathanReez Ahh, those are national identity cards.  Lots of countries have them.  Canada and the US only lack them because much of the function of an identity card is state/provincial here (e.g. driving privileges, or health insurance in Canada).  I googled and Ireland has a passport card separate from its identity card and its normal passport, so that's what I thought you meant.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie practically speaking the difference is purely semantic. Identity cards in Europe work in pretty much the same manner as passport cards in the US, once you leave your home country.

Comment: @JonathanReez in at least one EU country, the Netherlands, you don't need an ID card to qualify for a passport; you need to be a citizen to qualify for either one.

Comment: @JonathanReez There's one difference that isn't semantic:  national ID cards are identification cards that you can use to travel to some other countries; passport cards are cards that you can use to travel to some other countries that can be used for a few identification purposes.  The driver's license serves the main ID purpose here in CA/US.  In fact, until the US tightened its requirements in the wake of 9/11, Canadians only needed driver's licenses - ordinary ID - to enter the US, and ditto Americans to Canada.

Comment: @phoog I stand corrected. The requirement is to prove you're a citizen, which is to use the ID card by default for most citizens, but that's not the only way to do so.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie In that particular, it's true that you need a passport to get a passport card but Ireland is, to my knowledge, the only country in the EU to offer something like that.

Comment: (-1) Actually, as others noted, there is a bunch of countries with similar documents that could probably be amenable to some reciprocal recognition agreement. The answer ignores or downplays the real constraint: the US demands for a passport and, in many cases, a visa. For better or for worse, that (and not the lack of willing partners) is what stands in the way of easier travel between the EU and the US.

Comment: @Relaxed More immediate than the question of travel to Europe is, in my opinion, why a US passport card can be used to travel to (for example) Canada by land or sea, but not by air.  Canada already accepts US passport cards, but US law prohibits US citizens from using them to fly to the US ([8 CFR 235.1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/235.1) and [22 CFR 53](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/part-53)).  Questions about why the law is what it is belong on [Politics.SE].

Comment: @phoog Yes I noted that and that's a good point but I was reacting to the last paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the limitations on usage?

In order for other countries to accept a document from a different country the two must have some sort of an agreement between each other (or at least an official declaration from one of the parties involved). For passports, this is usually done when the two countries establish diplomatic relations and there are also international agreements on the matter such as the [ICAO guideline on the issuance of travel documents](https://www.iom.int/jahia/webdav/shared/shared/mainsite/activities/tcm/Assessment-Guide-PART1-Best-Practices-Jan-2010.pdf).

But identity cards are a relatively recent innovation in international travel, so there aren't any international standards on their acceptance. Likewise most countries still use outdated practices such as visa stickers and passport stamps, instead of switching to a fully electronic system. So in order to overcome inertia you need a good motivation, such as:

- The will to increase mutual integration, e.g. European Economic Area and the Gulf Cooperation Council accept ID cards of all member states.
- Facilitation of tourism, e.g. Georgia accepts European identity cards.
- Having a lot of people living on the border - this is one of the reasons why the US passport card was established in the first place.

So let's take a look at the [US passport card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Passport_Card) and how the reasons apply there:

- The US is currently not seeking increased integration with other countries. The closest country would be Canada which already accepts passport cards.
- I couldn't find any official rankings, but I suppose that most Americans travel to Canada, Mexico and the Carribean for vacations (all of which accept the passport) card.

  The next most popular choice would be the Schengen area, which would be hard pressed to accept non-EEA ID cards as there currently isn't a Schengen-wide database of entries and exits, so it would be difficult to track US citizens entering without a passport. You could of course issue some sort of an [entry-exit form](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74697/should-i-present-my-turkish-entry-exit-form-when-re-entering) instead of stamping the passport, but that would require a major change in the Schengen agreement which would probably be too expensive given the potential increase in the number of American visitors.

  The only country where I could expect a change would be the UK, but this would have to be coordinated with Ireland as the two countries are part of the [Common Travel Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area). The UK [already has a procedure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94100/what-does-the-uk-immigration-form-is-116-look-like) for issuing an entry-exit form and they do have an electronic database of all entries and exits, so it should be relatively painless.

  But most importantly the US itself would first need to allow citizens to use the passport card for **air travel**, as few people wish to travel outside of North America by sea. In its current form it's only usable by people living on the border and tourists going on Carribean cruises.
- As for people living on the border - Canada and Mexico already accept passport cards and the US doesn't share any other land borders. Originally this was the only reason why those cards were created in the first place (see @phoog's answer).

> Is it likely to change?

At this point we can only speculate. As of 2018 the answer is that there aren't any specific plans to expand the usage of the card.

Comment: (+1) Note that for the Schengen areas, a bigger issue (in my opinion) is the US own rather restrictive approach, demanding a biometric passport and pseudo-visa from everybody and an actual visa from some EU citizens, most notably Polish citizens. Without that, I would speculate that an agreement would be possible (incidentally the EU is supposed to roll out a database of entries and exits in the near future) but as you note the US is a lot more concerned about controlling its borders than facilitating travels by its own citizens.

Comment: An id card is not a recent innovation. Belgium introduced it in 1919 and made it mandatory for all inhabitants from the age of 15 on to have one. Nowadays you get one from 12 years old and at the time it was obviously not the bank card format that it has today. But neither did the passport look like it does today.

Comment: @ptityeti it's a recent innovation in terms of international travel, compared to passports.

Comment: One minor correction, the UK has a record of *most* entries and exits.

Comment: Passport cards are not valid for passengers arriving by sea from Europe, Asia, or South America, or indeed anywhere else apart from North America and the Caribbean.

Comment: @phoog yes because very few people arrive that way and those countries don't recognize passport cards anyway. The first step would probably be to allow it to be used for air travel, rather than extending it to Europe

Comment: @JonathanReez no, that is not why.  They are not valid for those travelers because 8 CFR 235.1 says that "A U.S. citizen who possesses a valid unexpired United States passport card, as defined in 22 CFR 53.1, may present the passport card when entering the United States **from contiguous territory or adjacent islands** at land or sea ports-of-entry." (Emphasis added.)  The passport card was developed as a way around requiring people who live near land borders to get proper passports, and that is why these restrictions exist.

Comment: @phoog yes I know what the law says but there's no reason why it couldn't be changed tomorrow if the US suddenly decides it wants to add the ID cards thing into the US-EU trade deal (for example). Just like ID cards in e.g. Czech Republic weren't originally created for traveling to the EU.

Comment: @JonathanReez of course (not that that would happen any time soon).  And you are right that allowing them for flights to Canada, Mexico, and the Caribbean is far more likely than for travel to Europe.  But the fact is that the reason for the restriction arises from the purpose of the cards in connection with the WHTI.  The US has been making documentary requirements *more* stringent for the last 17 years, not less.

Comment: @phoog I expect things to become more relaxed once biometric technologies become more widespread and tested. In theory, the only piece of ID you need is a microchip containing your GUID in the citizens database, which in turn contains your facial, fingerprint and retina information. You could even skip the microchip part and just have everyone scan their retina at the border ([the UK did it before](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/100613/9009)). That's a lot more secure than trusting a piece of paper.

Comment: @JonathanReez More secure than having the biometrics in a database is having them in the document itself -- which is already supported.

Comment: Actually there has been a Schengen entry-Exit form for Croatian ID holders pre-EU, as they could enter Hungary, Italy and Slovenia on it. And there are still entry-Exit forms for People with full passports or People who would endure serious issues if their passports are stamped

Answer (score 2):

The limitations on usage are specified in US law ([8 CFR 235.1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/235.1) and [22 CFR 53](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/part-53)).  All the discussion of reciprocal arrangements with other countries are irrelevant until that law changes.

Why those limitations?  See the [Intelligence Reform and Terrorism Prevention Act of 2004](http://news.findlaw.com/usatoday/docs/terrorism/irtpa2004.pdf), section 7209, subsection (a):

> (a) FINDINGS.—Consistent with the report of the National
>   Commission on Terrorist Attacks Upon the United States, Congress
>   makes the following findings:
>
> (1) Existing procedures allow many individuals to enter
>   the United States by showing minimal identification or without
>   showing any identification.
>
> (2) The planning for the terrorist attacks of September
>   11, 2001, demonstrates that terrorists study and exploit United
>   States vulnerabilities.
>
> (3) Additional safeguards are needed to ensure that terrorists
>   cannot enter the United States.

The passport card was developed as a mechanism for those who had been accustomed to visiting adjacent territory with only a driver's license, or similar identification, to continue to do so without the expense or inconvenience of a book-format passport.

Is it likely to change soon?  That is a matter of opinion, but I do not think you will find many people who are of the opinion that it will.

Comment: Why were the Carribean islands added on later though?

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm not sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if it were because of the fact that many US citizens in US possessions in the Caribbean (PR, USVI) were accustomed, like those living near Canada and Mexico, to traveling to nearby foreign places without a passport.